# Can not find where to publish a SAML app to G Suite

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We've already got an app on the G Suite Marketplace, but we are now looking to publish an app so that it's available to the general public when they go to G Suite --> Apps --> SAML Apps, then it's listed.

Specifically, we're looking to have our app be listed as part of this list:

[image: g suite saml apps]

Our application is SAML-enabled, supports SCIM provisioning, and is available with other IdPs. I checked the marketplace documentation and there's no mention of SAML.

Please let me know what steps we need to take to begin the submission process. Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked this blogpost [G Suite Single Sign-On via SAML](https://help.dialpad.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003085466-G-Suite-Single-Sign-On-via-SAML)?

Comment: The G Suite Marketplace does not support SAML apps for now.

Comment: @jess that link is for setting up an app for Single Sign-On rather than publishing an app to be available to others as a SAML SSO app

Comment: @AlejandroTamalet yeah I figured, but when I spoke to G Suite support they said to post here since there is no direct line to developer support. I keep getting told to go to different places :(

Comment: @EricT Do you find the way how we can publish our own app for SAML and Auto-provisioning? I am also looking for same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Requests for an app to be added to G Suite's pre-integrated SAML app catalog can be submitted using the [SAML Catalog Inclusion Request Form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQZYsNg2uu_PZYFeSKudkT6fV1PoMPylTfnHK6PWVYrdMtNQ/viewform).

Reference: [Set up your own custom SAML application](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519).

Comment: First we need to fill-up the form you mention or first we need to set up a project over here https://console.developers.google.com/. As I also can't find proper instruction for this which API I need to enable and where I can add the other details.

Comment: @RajJagani No idea- I'm not affiliated w/ Google, simply shared the links based on my previous experience.

Comment: Hi, Is this link to submit app still a valid procedure? I couldn't find any links in the docs. Please let me know. It would be really helpful. @Eran

Comment: @ShinyJos Sorry, I don't know- as I previously mentioned, I have no affiliation to Google, simply provided the information based on my experience with a similar issue.

Comment: @ShinyJos 

It appears that the referenced support article was modified sometime in the past year, as it previously included the following:

_"...If you're an application developer, you can use this form to request that your app be added to the pre-integrated SAML app catalog"_ (see [archived article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190716101516/https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519)).

Comment: Thank you so much for you support! I'll keep looking and post any updated I find here @Eran

Comment: @Eran, It appears they have paused accepting apps for now. I had posted the reply received from google here.

Comment: @Eran, how did you create your SAML app that also supports user provisioning?

Comment: @user3400371 I submitted the app through Google's now unavailable process- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63516771.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is searching for this in 2020, it appears they have paused accepting apps for now. I raised a support ticket for this and this was the reply from google

> Thank you for contacting Google Cloud Support, and I hope you’re doing
> great when you read this message. I understand that you want to
> publish your SAML application with G Suite. I see how important it is
> to pre-integrate your application in the G Suite catalog, and I'll be
> happy to help you today.
>
> Our Google SAML catalog is on pause for this year, meaning, our SAML
> team is not processing new requests from App Developers. Our
> recommendation is to fill out the SAML App Inclusion Request Form [1],
> so once the SAML team resumes SAML app inclusion requests, your
> application can be evaluated, and you can be contacted to inform you
> whether or not it’s approved. Also be aware we don’t know what date of
> next year our team will accept applications, but be confident that
> you’ll be contacted once we do so. For now, our options is to set up
> an App as a custom SAML application [2].

Comment: where did you raise your support ticket ?