# Steps to Publish a SAML App to Google Workspace

Tags: saml, google-workspace

I'm looking to develop and publish a SAML app to the Google Apps Marketplace. While I've found information on creating [custom SAML apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en), the goal is to make this app available within the [Pre-integrated SAML apps catalog](https://support.google.com/a/table/9217027?hl=en), allowing any of our tenants who use our SaaS application to easily integrate it for SAML-based authentication.
If anyone can provide steps to publish the SAML app to the apps catalog it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe this StackOverflow post would answer your question. Can you confirm? [Can not find where to publish a SAML app to G Suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938154/can-not-find-where-to-publish-a-saml-app-to-g-suite).