# How to publish a SAML app to the catalog?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace

I'm a developer, and I'd like my app to be available in the Google SAML apps catalog.
How can I do that?
I don't find any information about how or who to contact to register my app.

Can you help me?
Thanks

I want to publish SAML app to Google SAML apps catalog

Answer (score 0):

From discussion in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938154/can-not-find-where-to-publish-a-saml-app-to-g-suite) I would assume that Google is not accepting SAML applications anymore. They disabled it at one point before which they had a section in their guide for developers on how to submit a request to add their application to Google marketplace. They still haven't brought back that section, so the best you can do right now is to reach out to Google support and ask them directly and update here or in the question I linked before.